Is it okay to answer questions in Staging Ground?
I was under the impression that Staging Ground is only for post improvement, and not for trying to answer someone's question. The official guidelines and this meta question seem to imply that this is the case.
However, someone people seem to disagree, as evidenced by this question and the somewhat-disputed answer to that meta post.
Is there a consensus as to whether it's okay to help solve a problem in the comments of an SG post?

@dan1st That question is more about what to do once a problem's been solved. I'm more curious about whether the problem should be solved in the first place.

I voted to close it as a duplicate because in my view, the linked question and its answrers (apart from the reviewer guidelines) make it clear that you shouldn't try to solve questions in the Staging Ground.

Never thought about that; the staging ground adds a new layer of torture for people. Imagine knowing the answer and desperately wanting to be the first to share it to claim those sweet sweet internet points before someone else can - but you have to wait for the question to be promoted to the main site first. Madness.

@Gimby not really, it takes only one reviewer to publish the question to the main site and if you don't have review access on the SG you wouldn't even have been able to see the question.

@AbdulAzizBarkat one reviewer does not imply that it happens fast. I hope not!

@Gimby I was replying to "knowing the answer and desperately wanting to be the first to share it" if one knows the answer and feels that the question is on-topic and has no other issues nothing stops them from publishing the question. If the question does have some issues given this person knows the answer surely they can fix the issues?

The staging ground "is for" post improvement specifically, yes. That doesn't mean people shouldn't try to be helpful in other ways, IMO. However, because comments are not for answers, this should only be done when the commenter believes that the question cannot be salvaged (which roughly corresponds to using the "off-topic" or "duplicate" options in SG).
In the case of duplicates, a comment can help the OP understand why the underlying question is fundamentally the same question as another that's commonly asked, and how to apply the advice to the specific circumstance. Such content might be perceived by third parties as "an answer". There aren't hard lines here.
In the case of off-topic questions, a comment can suggest where the question might be on topic instead, or basic approaches to the problem. Similarly, whether others consider this "an answer" will depend on both specific details and on who is doing the evaluation - and I don't think it's worth worrying about.
Of course, people can be wrong about such decisions. In the current case, I suspect there's a valid underlying question (about how to specify dependencies for a project when packaging it for PyPI), but right now it seems unclear (it could actually be a completely different question about the specific package, and issues OP had with setting it up locally) and unfocused (maybe it's trying to be both?) It certainly also needs extensive editing even after that's resolved. But even so, the question seems perfectly on topic to me as a Python expert.
When someone writes ambiguously answer-like content in the SG, and the question eventually gets published to the main site, the comment will get wiped and that's fine. The comment has done its job and would be "no longer needed" if it had been preserved.
The SG exists so that we can improve the quality of newly added questions. But it necessarily also serves as an onboarding interface. If we actually care about the prospect of new users ever asking more than one question, then it's necessary to a) take the opportunity to explain how to do future questions better, even when the current question can't be accepted; and b) give new users the impression that it is, in fact, feasible to ask questions here. To this end, I believe it's helpful if new users aren't required to walk away empty-handed "because policy" in these circumstances.

I like the notion to help people but I think that you may want to much from the staging ground. It's won't be able to fix StackOverflow all by itself and many of the things mentioned like explaining to people what to do instead could also be done outside of the staging ground. I would like to limit the functions of the staging ground a bit more and keep the time of a question in staging to the bare minimum necessary to make the question barely ontopic or decide it can't be made so after a few tries. Everything else may come later, in my opinion.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution It's not so much that I want SG to do these things - just that I feel people should be able to try, and that it's likely net positive if they do.
